# add Welcome text with username to body of homepage

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add something along the lines of "Welcome, [user]" to the top of my homepage. I'd like it be as simple as possible (no SharePoint designer or customization to the master page). Just a simple CSS or javascript code (I still don't know the difference :) ) that I can add to a script editor or content editor web part. I found some codes that would include the user's picture and email, but I don't know code well enough to edit that part out. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this javascript SharePoint javascript object model to get the current logged in user. Put this code in a content editor web part on the homepage.

```
<div id="displayName"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
var user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
clientContext.load(user);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onUserNameSuccess, onUserNameFail);
function onUserNameSuccess() {
    document.getElementById("displayName").innerText = "Welcome, " + user.get_title();
    //To display last name first and for cases where full name consists of only two words.
    //var userToken = user.get_title().split(' ');
    //document.getElementById("displayName").innerText = "Welcome, " + userToken[1] + " " + userToken[0];

}

function onUserNameFail(args) {
    document.getElementById("displayName").innerText = 'Error:' + args.get_message();
}
//recommended to use ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded on sp.js
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Is there anyway to flip the name so it's First then Last, not last then first? That's just me being picky :)

Comment: @user69859 I have updated the answer with the code sample. You can extend the sample for more than 2 words in full name. The user full name is most likely set as "last, first" in your active directory or SharePoint user profile.